# AWS ECS Load Balancer switched from retuning 200 to 503 Status Code after a period of time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-ecr

Please I need help with understanding what could be the cause of the AWS ECS's Load Balancer switching from retuning 200 to 503 Status Code after a period of time. I am not an experienced DevOps engineer (especially, with Terraform) as I am developing backend services.

Below is the description of my services:

**VPC**: I am defining a default VPC:

```
resource "aws_default_vpc" "aws-vpc" {
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support   = true
  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.app_name}-vpc"
    Environment = var.APP_ENVIRONMENT
  }
}
```

**ECR and ECS cluster**: definition of both ECR and ECS cliuster:

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "aws-ecr" {
  name = "${var.upmentorship}-${var.APP_ENVIRONMENT}-ecr"
  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.upmentorship}-ecr"
    Environment = var.APP_ENVIRONMENT
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "aws-ecs-cluster" {
  name = "${var.upmentorship}-${var.APP_ENVIRONMENT}-cluster"
  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.upmentorship}-ecs"
    Environment = var.APP_ENVIRONMENT
  }
}
```

**ECS Service** is as follows:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "aws-ecs-core-api" {
  name                 = "${var.core-api}-ecs"
  cluster              = aws_ecs_cluster.aws-ecs-cluster.id
  task_definition      = aws_ecs_task_definition.aws-ecs-core-api-task.arn //"${aws_ecs_task_definition.aws-ecs-core-service-task.family}:${max(aws_ecs_task_definition.aws-ecs-core-service-task.revision, data.aws_ecs_task_definition.core-service.revision)}"
  launch_type          = "FARGATE"
  scheduling_strategy  = "REPLICA"
  desired_count        = 2
  force_new_deployment = true

  deployment_circuit_breaker {
    enable = true
    rollback = true
  }

  network_configuration {
    subnets          = aws_default_subnet.default_private.*.id
    assign_public_ip = true
    security_groups = [
      aws_security_group.service_security_group.id,
      aws_security_group.load_balancer_security_group.id
    ]
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.target_group.arn
    container_name   = "${var.core-api}-${var.APP_ENVIRONMENT}-container"
    container_port   = 8080
  }

  depends_on = [aws_lb_listener.listener]
}
```

The task definition referenced in the ECS service is as follows:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "aws-ecs-core-api-task" {
  family = "${var.core-api}-task"
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecsTaskExecutionRole.arn
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                      = "2048"
  memory                   = "8192"
  task_role_arn            = aws_iam_role.ecsTaskExecutionRole.arn
  #  container_definitions = jsonencode([local.task_definition_containers])
  container_definitions = <<DEFINITION
  [
    {
      "name": "${var.core-api}-${var.APP_ENVIRONMENT}-container",
      "image": "${aws_ecr_repository.aws-ecr.repository_url}:latest",
      "entryPoint": [],
      "environment": ${data.template_file.env_vars.rendered},
      "essential": true,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.log-group.id}",
          "awslogs-region": "${var.AWS_REGION}",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "${var.core-api}-${var.APP_ENVIRONMENT}"
        }
      },
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 8080,
          "hostPort": 8080
        }
      ],
      "cpu": 1024,
      "memory": 4096,
      "memory_reservation": 8192,
      "networkMode": "awsvpc"
    }
  ]
DEFINITION
  tags = {
    name        = "${var.core-api}-ecs-td"
    environment = var.APP_ENVIRONMENT
  }
}
```

The Security Group refrenced in the service is defined below:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "service_security_group" {
  vpc_id = aws_default_vpc.aws-vpc.id

  ingress {
    from_port       = 0
    to_port         = 0
    protocol        = "-1"
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.load_balancer_security_group.id]
  }

  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.core-api}-service-sg"
    Environment = var.APP_ENVIRONMENT
  }
}
```

**Load Balancer**: The definition is as follows:

```
resource "aws_alb" "application_load_balancer" {
  name               = "${var.core-api}-${var.APP_ENVIRONMENT}-alb"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  subnets            = aws_default_subnet.default_public.*.id
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.load_balancer_security_group.id]

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.core-api}-alb"
    Environment = var.APP_ENVIRONMENT
  }
}
```

**Security Group**: I am definiting the security group for the Load balancer below:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "load_balancer_security_group" {
  vpc_id = aws_default_vpc.aws-vpc.id

  ingress {
    from_port        = 80
    to_port          = 80
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }
  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.core-api}-sg"
    Environment = var.APP_ENVIRONMENT
  }
}
```

**Load Balancer Target Group**: I am definiting the target group for the Load balancer below:

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "target_group" {
  name        = "${var.core-api}-${var.APP_ENVIRONMENT}-tg"
  port        = 80
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  target_type = "ip"
  vpc_id      = aws_default_vpc.aws-vpc.id

  health_check {
    healthy_threshold   = "3"
    interval            = "30"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    matcher             = "200,301,302"//"200"
    timeout             = "10"
    path                = "/debug/liveness"
    unhealthy_threshold = "10"
  }

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.core-api}-lb-tg"
    Environment = var.APP_ENVIRONMENT
  }
}
```

Now, I understand the Load Balancer needs toi listen for incomming request from the container, so I define a Load Balancer listener below:

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_alb.application_load_balancer.id
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.target_group.id
  }
}
```

Lastly, since I am considering autoscalling the container's CPU and memory, I am defining the autoscalling target and policies below:

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "ecs_target" {
  max_capacity       = 2
  min_capacity       = 1
  resource_id        = "service/${aws_ecs_cluster.aws-ecs-cluster.name}/${aws_ecs_service.aws-ecs-core-api.name}"
  scalable_dimension = "ecs:service:DesiredCount"
  service_namespace  = "ecs"
}
resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "ecs_policy_memory" {
  name               = "${var.core-api}-${var.APP_ENVIRONMENT}-memory-autoscaling"
  policy_type        = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  resource_id        = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.resource_id
  scalable_dimension = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.scalable_dimension
  service_namespace  = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.service_namespace

  target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "ECSServiceAverageMemoryUtilization"
    }

    target_value = 80
  }
}

resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "ecs_policy_cpu" {
  name               = "${var.core-api}-${var.APP_ENVIRONMENT}-cpu-autoscaling"
  policy_type        = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  resource_id        = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.resource_id
  scalable_dimension = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.scalable_dimension
  service_namespace  = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.service_namespace

  target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization"
    }

    target_value = 80
  }
}
```

Afterwards, I applied the definitions and deployed my code to ECR and ECS using Github Actions (this works fine). Upon successful deployment, I can access the API (the health check path is accessible and other endpoints I created). However, after a period of time, it would start returning 503 status code. What do you think is wrong in my Terraform definition?

**UPDATE**: Here is Task's log:

[Task's Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiCyl.png)

[Detail of an event in the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrgS4.png)

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: You need to check your task's logs in CloudWatch Logs to see if it crashed or something. It sounds like your task is failing/crashing after some time.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkB. I will update the original post with the screenshot of the log from the Task.

Comment: Those aren't the logs, those are the events.

Comment: The logs from the container are healthy. There are no logs of the service stopping or restarting.

Comment: The container's logs are accessible via CloudWatch and it looks pretty health

Comment: Health check failed with code `405`. If the reason for that isn't showing up in the application's logs, then you need to increase the logging level. It sounds like your application is blocking `GET` requests to the health check URL.

Comment: Ok looking further, the Task itself does not have logs entry at all. The only logs I can access is the application log which seems very fine.

Comment: Hmm I see but it returns 200 for a few minutes before it starts returning 503....which makes it a bit confusing.

Comment: It is probably routing traffic by default during the health check grace period, which is why you get 200 for a few minutes, and then it shuts down the service due to failing health checks, which is why you start getting 503. The whole thing is due to the fact that your health checks are failing, and the event logs say that is because your health check endpoint is blocking GET requests.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is between a task log, and an application log. Those are really two names for the same thing.

Comment: 503, from the loadbalancer is `service unavailable` it basically means there are not health containers available to serve traffic for the ELB. Like @MarkB say, chances are when you start the container its fine until after the first helth check. for the healthcheck returning 405 is `method not allowed` its like your health check is targetting a valid path but with an http method which the code doesnt allow

Comment: @MarkB, what I meant by the application log is actually the logs from the container itself; i have Cloudwatch displaying those logs and I can access them. However, the Task Log is empty; no entries whatsoever.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, thanks for the input. I will spend more time today looking into this. I will revert.

Comment: A quick question: Does the health check endpoint needs to be running on a separate PORT (different from that of the container)?

Comment: Thanks, Mark and Chris. I have been able to resolve the issue and everything seems to be working reliably now. The issue was in path passes for a health check. It was not correct.